# Как вывести несколько переменных с похожим названием разом?

Tags: python, ос

Как сделать чтобы переменная "av" собирала информацию об установленных антивирусах и выводила все установленные одной переменной?
Извините за глупый вопрос, я новичок в python.

Как пример: Windows Defender, Avast, ESET

```
import os

if os.path.exists('C:\\Program Files\\Windows Defender'):
   av = 'Windows Defender'
if os.path.exists('C:\\Program Files\\AVAST Software\\Avast'):
   av = 'Avast'
if os.path.exists('C:\\Program Files\\AVG\\Antivirus'):
   av = 'AVG'
if os.path.exists('C:\\Program Files\\Avira\\Launcher'):
   av = 'Avira'
if os.path.exists('C:\\Program Files\\IObit\\Advanced SystemCare'):
   av = 'Advanced SystemCare'
if os.path.exists('C:\\Program Files\\Bitdefender Antivirus Free'):
   av = 'Bitdefender'
if os.path.exists('C:\\Program Files\\COMODO\\COMODO Internet Security'):
   av = 'Comodo'
if os.path.exists('C:\\Program Files\\DrWeb'):
   av = 'Dr.Web'
if os.path.exists('C:\\Program Files\\ESET\\ESET Security'):
   av = 'ESET'
if os.path.exists('C:\\Program Files\\GRIZZLY Antivirus'):
   av = 'Grizzly Pro'
if os.path.exists('C:\\Program Files\\Kaspersky Lab'):
   av = 'Kaspersky'
if os.path.exists('C:\\Program Files\\IObit\\IObit Malware Fighter'):
   av = 'Malvare fighter'
if os.path.exists('C:\\Program Files\\Norton Security'):
   av = 'Norton'
if os.path.exists('C:\\Program Files\\Panda Security\\Panda Security Protection'):
   av = 'Panda Security'
if os.path.exists('C:\\Program Files\\360\\Total Security'):
   av = '360 Total Security'

print(av)
```

Comment: Используйте списки (тип `list`). В первом храните пути до антивирусов, проверяя их наличие в цикле (`for`), вместо кучи `if`’ов. А во втором храните результат (дополняя через метод `append`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os

avs = list()

if os.path.exists('C:\\Program Files\\Windows Defender'):
   avs.append('Windows Defender');
if os.path.exists('C:\\Program Files\\AVAST Software\\Avast'):
   avs.append('Avast');
if os.path.exists('C:\\Program Files\\AVG\\Antivirus'):
   avs.append('AVG');
if os.path.exists('C:\\Program Files\\Avira\\Launcher'):
   avs.append('Avira');
if os.path.exists('C:\\Program Files\\IObit\\Advanced SystemCare'):
   avs.append('Advanced SystemCare');
if os.path.exists('C:\\Program Files\\Bitdefender Antivirus Free'):
   avs.append('Bitdefender');
if os.path.exists('C:\\Program Files\\COMODO\\COMODO Internet Security'):
   avs.append('Comodo');
if os.path.exists('C:\\Program Files\\DrWeb'):
   avs.append('Dr.Web');
if os.path.exists('C:\\Program Files\\ESET\\ESET Security'):
   avs.append('ESET');
if os.path.exists('C:\\Program Files\\GRIZZLY Antivirus'):
   avs.append('Grizzly Pro');
if os.path.exists('C:\\Program Files\\Kaspersky Lab'):
   avs.append('Kaspersky');
if os.path.exists('C:\\Program Files\\IObit\\IObit Malware Fighter'):
   avs.append('Malware fighter');
if os.path.exists('C:\\Program Files\\Norton Security'):
   avs.append('Norton');
if os.path.exists('C:\\Program Files\\Panda Security\\Panda Security Protection'):
   avs.append('Panda Security');
if os.path.exists('C:\\Program Files\\360\\Total Security'):
   avs.append('360 Total Security');

for av in avs:
   print(av);
```

Comment: Ну уже бы могли и оптимизации расказать: a) держать общий путь (корень поиска) в отдельной переменной), б) использовать словарь (или просто список) с каталогами поиска, в) использовать `os.path.join()`, г) использовать `join()` для результата. Вообще вот это всё делается в половину меньше строк.